# How to determine if current locale uses UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: bash, locale, unicode

I would like to determine if the user's locale uses UTF-8 encoding.

This seems a little bit ugly:

```
[[ $LANG =~ UTF-8$ ]] && echo "Uses UTF-8 encoding.."
```

is there a more general/portable way?

Comment: What exactly you want? (why `[ $LANG =~ UTF-8$ ]] && echo "Uses UTF-8 encoding.."` is ugly?)

Comment: @Pandya Will it work on all systems? What if `LANG` is not defined? What if `LANG` uses lower case letters `utf-8`, and so on..

Comment: @Pandya It fails if the encoding is defined through `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL` or `LANGUAGE`, or if the encoding name uses a variation on the suffix such as `utf8`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) :

> On POSIX platforms, locale identifiers are defined similarly to the
>   BCP 47 definition of language tags, but the locale variant modifier is
>   defined differently, and the character encoding is included as a part
>   of the identifier.
>
> It is defined in this format:
>   [language[_territory][.codeset][@modifier]]. (For example, Australian
>   English using the UTF-8 encoding is en_AU.UTF-8.)

However, if the codeset suffix is missing in the locale identifier, for example as in `en_AG` (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210898/what-is-the-difference-between-locale-en-ag-and-en-ag-utf8/210905#210905) question), then the codeset is defined by a default setting for that locale, which could very well be UTF-8. As a result, the current encoding cannot be determined by looking at the LANG environment variable.

Further, the `locale` command only shows the current values of the environment variables.. so it seems that that command cannot be used to determine the codeset either..

However, there is a Perl module [`I18N::Langinfo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/I18N::Langinfo), see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261655/how-to-get-the-default-encoding-of-current-os-in-perl-script) that seems to be a solution:

```
perl -MI18N::Langinfo=langinfo,CODESET -E 'say "Uses UTF-8 encoding .." if langinfo(CODESET()) eq "UTF-8"'
```

This Perl module is a wrapper for the C library function [nl_langinfo](http://man.he.net/man3/nl_langinfo).

Comment: For people wanting to avoid calling Perl, the manpage of [nl_langinfo(3)](http://man.he.net/man3/nl_langinfo) on CODESET notes "_This is the same string that you get with `locale charmap`._"

Answer (score 7):

There is `charmap` attribute in the LC_CTYPE locale category that can be used for this:

```
locale charmap | grep -qi 'utf-\+8' && echo "Uses UTF-8 encoding.."
```

It is a bit more robust that parse the locale name.

(answer updated base on the Bluehorn suggestion, thanks!)

Comment: Just learned: The easiest way is calling `locale charmap` which will just return the character set of the current locale.

Answer (score 6):

On POSIX system, you can use [locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/locale.html):

```
$ if (locale | grep -e 'utf8' -e 'UTF-8') >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo UTF8; fi
UTF8
```

Answer (score 1):

To take care of the cases in which the locale string contains a lowercase `utf8` substring, you can set `bash`'s `nocasematch` option and make the dash optional:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
[[ $LANG =~ UTF-?8$ ]] && echo "Uses UTF-8 encoding.."
```