# What is the difference between locale en_AG and en_AG.utf8?

Tags: locale, unicode

Running `locale -av` in the terminal window gives me (only showing first two items of output):

```
locale: en_AG           archive: /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    title | English language locale for Antigua and Barbuda
   source | Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  address | 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | English
territory | Antigua and Barbuda
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2008-09-16
  codeset | UTF-8

locale: en_AG.utf8      archive: /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    title | English language locale for Antigua and Barbuda
   source | Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  address | 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | English
territory | Antigua and Barbuda
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2008-09-16
  codeset | UTF-8
```

- What is the difference beween locale `en_AG` and `en_AG.utf8`?
- Why is locale `en_AG` using UTF-8 codeset, even though there is no codeset modifier in its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you give a locale by the name `language_COUNTRY`, you actually specify one of the locales defined as `language_COUNTRY.codeset`: the default one for this language and country. In the case of `en_AG`, it appears that the default codeset is UTF8. For `en_US`, it is ISO-8859-1, and therefore `en_US` is in fact equivalent to `en_US.ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: An implication of this behavior is that one cannot determine the encoding used by the user's current locale by  inspecting the LANG variable as in  [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210602/how-to-determine-if-current-locale-uses-utf-8-encoding) question. For example, to check if the current locale's encoding is UTF-8, it is not sufficient to check if the LANG variable matches the strings `utf8`, `UTF-8` or `utf-8`.

Comment: So then en_AG locale is identical to en_AG.utf8 locale ? (en_AG is just an alias for en_AG.utf8)

Comment: In your case yes. If locale en_AG.ISO-8859-1 is possible and if it were the only en_AG locale you have, then en_AG would be an alias to en_AG.ISO-8859-1.